# Lombok Annotations with DynamoDB annotations

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, lombok

I have a DAO like:

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName="tableName")
    public class DAO {
        @DynamoDBHashKey
        private String field1;

        @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName="index_name")
        @DynamoDBRangeKey
        private String field2;
    }
```

Problem is when I am trying to use the DAO to make a load call using DynamoDBMapper with field1 as the hash key to obtain the item, it throws a DynamoDBException saying:
 **Null key found for public DAO.getField2()**
but actually table has value corresponding to field2. 
Question, is this because of Lombok annotation instead of the manual mutator code and or in general we use Lombok and DynamoDBAnnotations together?

Comment: I haven't used Lombok, but I don't see why it would cause problems. It sounds like you are **only** using the `hashKey` of the item: what DynamoDBMapper method are you calling (which DynamoDB API)?

Comment: I am using load() method. Actually figured that this happens when there is a combination of hash and range key, load requires that both are passed to table to make the request. Therefore, query() needs to be used in that case since it allows query over only the hash key. And that worked for me. Therefore, lombok works fine with DynamoDB annotations since we can annotate the DAO fields directly.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I guessed. Lombok should do all of its magic beforehand, and the DynamoDBMapper should still have access to all of the annotations. I think the way it still works is you should go either annotate the getters/setters, or annotate the fields, but not mixing both. It eventually calls `GetItem` which requires both, hence why you were getting that error in the Mapper. Glad to see you figured it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a little more of an explanation and a **TL;DR**

You are calling the `load` method, which is mapped to the [`GetItem`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) call. The `DynamoDBMapper` is trying to map that request based on your annotations. Your class has the `@DynamoDBRangeKey` annotation, and the `GetItem` call needs the full primary key to get the item, which means that the mapper will build out the primary key for the object.

Since Lombok has already generated your code (before runtime), it is not affecting the annotations you have already placed. And also since your annotations are on the fields rather than applying them to the getters, the mapper it is calling the generated Lombok getter. When it tries to serialize into a request, however, that getter is returning `null` because you have only set the hashKey.

**TL;DR**: `load()` translates to `GetItem` API which requires both the hashKey and the rangeKey since both annotations are present on your class.